# how to display names in alphabetical groups in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i am getting an array from the database and i am printing that array names using angularjs ng-repeat, i want to display that names like     



 
N
      Naresh
    s
      Sateesh
      sandeep
      suresh

```
[
  {
    "name": "suresh",
  },
  {
    "name": "naresh",
  },
  {
    "name": "sateesh",
  },
  {
    "name": "sandeep",
  }
]
I want to display the names as below using ng-repeat
 N
  Naresh
s
  Sateesh
  sandeep
  suresh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pre-process your array and use a nested ng-repeat:

In your controller:

```
$scope.datas = [
                    { "name": "suresh"  },
                    { "name": "naresh"  },
                    { "name": "sateesh" },
                    { "name": "sandeep" }
                ];

$scope.processed = process($scope.datas);

console.log($scope.processed);

function process(arr) {
    var processed = {};
    arr.forEach(item => {
        var key = item.name[0];
        processed[key] = processed[key] || [];
        processed[key].push(item.name);
    });
    return processed;
}
```

In your template:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in processed">
        {{key}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in value | orderBy "> {{item }} </li>
        </ul>                           
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i want to display like 'N' infront of the N letter name  's' infront of the S letter names

Comment: Ok, I understand

Comment: but for small letters and capitals letters are taking different

Comment: You can just always turn the key to lowercase:
var key = item.name.toLowerCase()[0];